# Why does cactiStyle() strip settings from color()?

Tags: grafana, graphite

We want to apply [cactiStyle](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.cactiStyle) to certain metrics, so that we can display `current, max, min` for just those metrics. However, we also have custom [colors](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.color) assigned to our graphs. If I try to apply `cactiStyle()` to a metric that also has `color()`, the color is stripped away. Below are an example before and after `cactiStyle` is applied.

`alias(color(path.to.metric.users,'E24D42'),'Users')`:
[image: without cacti]
`cactiStyle(alias(color(path.to.metric.users,'E24D42'),'Users'))`:
[image: with cacti]

When we apply `cactiStyle` to our metrics, the color of the metric follows the default behavior, which is order listed. Can I get around this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Grafana doesn't use the graphite `color` function, I'm guessing that you have overrides specified in Grafana (which are done on a per-series-name basis) that no longer apply when you use cactiStyle to rename the series.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by _per series name basis_? How is that different from the examples I gave? Thanks

Comment: Are your graphs being generated using Grafana or graphite-web?  At first glance they appear to be Grafana graphs, and Grafana *does not* get any color information from Graphite.  What it *does* do is support specifying per-series colors in the dashboard, and those colors are mapped to the series names.  When you use `cactiStyle` you are changing the name of the series, so those color mappings will no longer be valid and you'll get the default colors.

Comment: What do you mean by _per-series colors_? Is that not what I've defined? I've tried wrapping everything, including the `cactiStyle` in a `color()`, but it doesn't change anything. Can I name the series and reference that somehow in `color()`?

Comment: I should mention that this is a templated dashboard (generated via js), so if you're referring to clicking the specific series in the legend and specifying the color there, I don't think that will work for me unless I can do that programmatically somehow